# Area of kite reason

Tags: geometry, area

I know the area of a kite is $\frac{d_1d_2}{2}$, but why does this happen?
I know the two triangles formed by one of the diagonals are isosceles but I don't know if that relates to the reason of the area.

Answer (score 2):

The diagonals $d_1$ and $d_2$ divide a kite into four quarters with the same area, which equals to $\frac{d_1d_2}{8}$, because $d_1$ and $d_2$ intersect at a right angle and halve themselves. Hence the area of the kite is $\frac{d_1d_2}{2}$.

Comment: Each of the triangles wouldn't have the same area, would they? Both diagonals won't necessarily bisect each other; only one of them is a perpendicular of the other.

Comment: @Christopher Sapinski Oops, sorry, I'm not observant at all, I thought that you've meant nothing but rhombus. But it doesn't change much: diagonals are still perpendicular. As you've mentioned, the two triangles formed by one of the diagonals (let it be $d_1$) will be isosceles, and their areas are equal to $S_1 = \frac{d_1h_1}{2}$ and $S_2 = \frac{d_1h_2}{2}$, where $h_1$ and $h_2$ are two parts of the another diagonal ($d_2 = h_1 + h_2$). So the area of the kite is equal to $S_1 + S_2 = \frac{d_1d_2}{2}$.